# Build not found in Phonegap 3.0 for android

Tags: android, cordova

I have installed Cordova along with Phonegap and installed node.js in my system(ubuntu)
by using following commands:

Install Nodejs http://nodejs.org/

Install Cordova 3.0.x

```
 $ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Install Phone Gap 3.0.x

```
 $ sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Then i created project using phonegap command:

```
 $ phonegap create hello
```

Trying to run into my local by using following command:

```
 $ phonegap local run andriod
```

Now at first i am getting following error:

```
shoaib@shoaib:~/Documents/hello$ phonegap local run android
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. /home/shoaib/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.0.0/bin/create: line 54: jar: command not found
```

This i solved by running following command:

```
ls -la /home/shoaib/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.0.0/bin
```

Now when i again run 
    $ phonegap local run andriod

I am getting below error:

```
root@shoaib:/home/shoaib/Documents/hello# phonegap local run android
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[error] An error occurred while building the android project. /bin/sh: 1: /home/shoaib/Documents/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: not found
```

I am using Android SDK 17
and version as 4.2.2 .
Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey got the solution.

I install open jdk 6.0 and problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. build and run were missing along with a few other files and lib was an empty directory. Downloaded cordova-android from [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android) extracted and copied everything from its `/bin/templates/cordova/` to the project (`/platforms/android/cordova/`). Then I could build and install the app.

Still had to start the emulator, check the running emulator with `platforms/android/cordova/lib/list-started-emulators` and then pass it when installing or it would take forever to install it on an emulator.

```
$ platforms/android/cordova/lib/list-started-emulators 
emulator-5554
$ phonegap install --emulator=emulator-5554 android
```

Answer (score 1):

I had already installed the JDK but the same error.
To fix this I just removed the phone test project and make sure that:

- Java, javac and jar where in the path

(both should work)

```
java -version
javac -version
jar -version
```

Android sdk path was properly set and JAVA_HOME environment variable was properly set.

Then I remake the project and everything worked.